# Is $\left\|A^TA(x-y)\right\| = \left\|A^TA\right\|\times \left\|x-y\right\|$ correct? $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

In the derivation of following, I meet a dumb problem:

Note:
1. $\left\|\: \cdot \,\right\|$ is the $l_2$ norm.
2.  $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $
3. $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

$$\frac{\left\|A^TA\,x-A^TA\,y\right\|}{\left\|x-y\right\|} = \frac{\left\|A^TA\,(x-y)\right\|}{\left\|x-y\right\|} =  \frac{\left\|A^TA\right\|\times \left\|x-y\right\|}{\left\|x-y\right\|} = \left\|A^TA\right\|_2 = \sigma_{max}\left(A^TA\right)$$

Is this correct?

I think  $\left\|A^TA\,(x-y)\right\| = \left\|A^TA\right\|\times \left\|x-y\right\|$ seems not true. Why or why not?

Comment: Why don't you try a few random examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $\| A^T A \|$ means the Euclidean operator norm induced by $\| x \|$ you only have inequality, not equality. For an extreme example, you can have nonzero $A,x$ such that $Ax=0$, in which case $\| A^T A x \|=0$ but $\| A^T A \| \| x \| \neq 0$.

Comment: Why the last statement true?

Comment: @sleevechen Try $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: One more confirm, so $l_2$-norm here is the same for a square matrix and a vector? I mean $\| A^T A x \|=0$ and $\| A^T A \| \| x \| \neq 0$. The previous one is for the vector, and the later one is for a matrix.

Comment: @sleevechen These are not the same norm. The Euclidean operator norm is *induced* by the Euclidean vector norm, but they are not the same. The analogue of the Euclidean vector norm for matrices is called the Frobenius norm.